# How to stop dired printing "Reverting buffer ..."

Tags: dired, auto-revert-mode, revert-buffer

After setting `dired-auto-revert-buffer` to `t`, even when I'm working on a buffer of file that may produce some results, the message keep printing if there is a `dired` buffer behind current buffer. This is really annoying. How can I completely disable it? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Customize option **`auto-revert-verbose`** to `nil`.  `C-h v` tells you this:

> **`auto-revert-verbose`** is a variable defined in `autorevert.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> When `nil`, Auto-Revert Mode does not generate any messages.
>
> When non-`nil`, a message is generated whenever a file is reverted.
>
> You can *customize* this variable.

It's kind of a shame that the doc of `auto-revert-mode` does not mention this option. Neither the doc string (`C-h v`) nor the Emacs manual (node [Reverting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html)) mentions it.

(I filed Emacs bug #[25162](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25162), as an enhancement request to mention it.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I looked into `dired`, but find no hints of it. I didn't known this is an auto revert mode issue.

Comment: You could presumably set this buffer-local in a dired hook if you still want the message when visiting a file.